# remove object from json array based on condition using java

Tags: java, arrays, json

In my application I get output in the form of Json array as below

```
{Students: [{Name: Harry,Subject: maths,}, 
               {Name:Ryan,Subject: Biology,}, 
               {Name:James ,Subject: maths,}]}
```

From this array I want to remove the whole object based on the applied condition.

Lets say if Subject is "Biology" remove the whole object and return:

```
{Students: [{Name: Harry,Subject: maths,}, 
            {Name:James ,Subject: maths,}]}
```

How can I achieve this using java programming.

Answer (score 0):

If You have the class (I assume Student here) you can unmarshall the object list using a serialization/deserialization library like Jackson to a collection like List and then do simple list manipulation. Assuming you are receiving the JSON as a string named students

```
List<Student> list = mapper.readValue(students,
TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Student.class));
```

This should work.

Edit:
Since you asked for a version that reads JSON from a file, there you go:

```
public JSONArray getFilteredStudents(String jsonFilePath) throws Exception {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(jsonFilePath);
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(fileReader);

        JSONArray students = (JSONArray) json.get("Students");
        Iterator itr = students.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) itr.next();
            if (obj.get("Subject").equals("Biology")) {
                itr.remove();
            }
        }

        return students;
}
```

Download json-simple library from [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/detail?name=json-simple-1.1.1.jar).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response but  its reading JSON output from a file. There is no class for this . Is there a way to do this in this case?

Comment: Hi mushfek0001, thanks but somehow it is not able to parse the Json file. I get error message as:
Exception in thread "main" Unexpected character (S) at position 1.
 at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)

. My Json.txt file has:
 {Students: [{Name: Harry,Subject: maths,}, 
               {Name:Ryan,Subject: Biology,}, 
               {Name:James ,Subject: maths,}]}

Comment: That's because you have an ill-formatted JSON file. JSON file usually contains quoted (key, value) pairs. Try this https://gist.github.com/mushfek0001/d3c2ba8ad69944904d1f

Comment: Oh I also noticed that the sample JSON you have posted in the question has comma (,) after subject value which isn't correct either. You'll have to have a valid JSON to do any type of manipulation. Now, if you want to correctly format it first and then parse or something that's whole another problem. P.S.: I actually created my own sample JSON to test when writing code so that's why I didn't notice these earlier.